# Grails Criteria List - ilike search multiple columns with OR

Tags: grails, criteria

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and am trying to create a criteria list that returns rows matching either the code or name. The list is being created based on a search. I'm able to create the list with just the code, but when I add the or{} I get a runtime error. How could I search both the code and name and return all matches?

```
Criteria c

c = ProductCode.createCriteria()

if (c) {
    list = c.list(params) {
        if (params.query) {
            or {
                ilike("code", params.query + "%")
                ilike("name", params.query + "%")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your runtime error? And what are the fields of `ProductCode`?

Comment: Easy enough, name was spelled slightly different. Otherwise the code works perfectly. Thanks for pointing out the obvioius for me, ha